# How to automate clicking on a button in webpage to download a file?

Tags: pandas, xml, button, export

In the following web page:

https://www.iadb.org/en/transparency/sanctioned-firms-and-individuals

There is a table and an "Export to Excel" button, as shown in the following image.

[image]

What I need to do is to read in the table below the highlighted button, but the problem is that that table is spread over multiple pages and the number of pages might vary over time.

**Question**. Is it possible to "Export to Excel" that table from Python (i.e.: writing a code that gives the command to "click" on "Export to Excel" button)?

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to it on Windows.

First:

- follow the [instructions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#installing-python-bindings-for-selenium) to install [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html)
- download `ChromeDriver` from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and save it to the directory of your choice (say "C:/temp").

Then:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Setup
service = Service("C:/temp/chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# Go to the page
driver.get("https://www.iadb.org/en/transparency/sanctioned-firms-and-individuals")

# Clic "Export to Excel" button
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="santioned-table-element"]/button')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="santioned-table-element"]/button')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()

driver.close()
```

You will find the file **"Report_en.xls"** in your default download directory.